# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC action arguments are not passed by named route

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

My ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app has a home page and an expenditure page which is linked to from the home page with an integer `systemId` parameter passed to it's default Index action method which just prints the passed `systemId` value in it's associated view.

```
public class ExpenditureController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int systemId)
    {
        ViewBag.SystemID = systemId;
        return View();
    }
}
```

The view is as simple as

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Expenditure";
}
<div class="container">
    <h1>System id is @ViewBag.SystemId</h1>
</div>
```

The home controller defines a route data instance which is passed to the home view which renders the link to the Expenditure controller's action id, passing an id.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _routeDataExpenditureMapping;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
  
        _routeDataExpenditureMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
              {
                  { "controller", "Expenditure" },
                  { "action", "Index" },
                  { "systemId", "15153" }
              };
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ExpenditureMappingRouteData = _routeDataExpenditureMapping;
 
        return View();
    }
}
```

The Home view

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>
  <h2>Testing routes</h2>
  <p>
    <h3>Using named routes and route data</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a asp-route="systemid" asp-all-route-data="@ViewBag.ExpenditureMappingRouteData">Expenditure</a></li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Finally, the `Program.cs`, which defines the default controller route as well as the named route `systemid`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{code?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "systemid", pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{systemid}");

app.Run();
```

I would have expected that clicking the Home view link to ExpenditureController would result in the systemId parameter being passed to that controller's Index action method but it's not, the systemId parameter is always 0.

If I change the order of the MapControllerRoute calls so that the systemId route mapping comes first, then it all works. With the original route mapping order in place, I'm assuming what's happening is that the default route mapping picks up the URL for the link to Expenditure and matches it to the default mapping because it that mapping is declared first, but I would have expected the systemId mapping to be selected because I've explicitly specified it the Expenditure link, i.e. `<a asp-route="systemid" ...`

Surely explicitly specifying the route mapping using the asp-route attribute should avoid matching to the default route mapping (yes I know it's declared first), otherwise where's the point of the `asp-route` attribute?

Of course, I can do away with the systemID route mapping and just use

```
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute(Name = "id")] int systemId)
{
   ViewBag.SystemID = systemId;
   return View();
}
```

but it doesn't help me understand why `asp-route` doesn't appear to work.

Can anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made little mistake in home controller. try with this snippet. Hope it will solve your problem. [For details follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <h2>Testing routes</h2>
    <p>
        <h3>Using named routes and route data</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-route-systemid="@ViewBag.ExpenditureMappingRouteData" asp-all-route-data="@ViewBag.ExpenditureMappingRouteData">Expenditure</a></li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `asp-route` attribute is used for creating a URL linking directly to a named route.

In your case, you use `asp-route="systemid"` in `<a></a>` tag, If you want this `<a></a>` tag hit the `index` action in `ExpenditureController`, you just need to add a route attribute with `Name= "systemid"`

```
 public class ExpenditureController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Expenditure/Index", Name = "systemid")]
        public IActionResult Index(int systemId)
        {
            ViewBag.SystemID = systemId;
            return View();
        }
```

Please refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Hi @endurium, Can this answer help you solve your issue?